# Prove $\gcd(b^2+ab,a^2+2ab)=1 $ if $\gcd(a,b)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I want to show that for $\gcd(a,b)=1$, $a,b \in \mathbf{Z}$, $\gcd(b^2+ab,a^2+2ab)=1$.

I think the first step is something like this
$$\gcd(b^2+ab,a^2+2ab)=\gcd(b(a+b),a(a+b)+ab). $$

I have two properties that can be used. There are

1/ $\gcd(a+b,c)=\gcd(a,c)$ if $b \vdots a$.

2/ $\gcd(ab,c)=\gcd(a,c)$ if $\gcd(b,c)=1$.

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Suppose that $\gcd(b^2ab,a^2+2ab)>1$, then for some prime $p$ we have $p\mid b^2+ab=b(a+b)$ and $p\mid a^2+2ab=a(a+2b)$, so we have 4 cases to consider.

Comment: Apply the first dupe's Lemma (= $3$ applications of "2/")   using $\,A,B,K,M = b,a+b,a,(a+2b),\,$  using "1/" to deduce $\, 1 = (A,K) = (A,M) =\ldots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to coprimality of $a,b$ we have $b$ coprime with $a^2+2ab$, $a$ coprime with $b^2+ab$, hence by property 2 we can simplify
$$
\gcd(b^2+ab,a^2+2ab)=\gcd(b+a,a+2b).
$$
Another useful property is $\gcd(m,n)=\gcd(m+n,n)$, so we continue
$$
\gcd(b+a,a+2b)=\gcd(b+a,b)=\gcd(a,b)=1.
$$

Comment: I have a question. Why is $b$ coprime with $a^2+2ab$?

Comment: @FactorY Any common factor of $b$ and $a^2+2ab$ would have to divide $a^2$, impossible as $a^2$ and $b$ are coprime.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Let $d\neq 1$ a prime number s.t. $$d\mid b^2+ab=b(a+b)\quad \text{and}\quad d\mid a^2+2ab= a(a+2b).$$

- Suppose $d\mid b$. Then $\gcd(d,a)=1$, and thus $d\mid a+2b$ and thus $$a\equiv -2b\equiv 0\pmod d,$$
  which contradict $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Therefore $d\nmid b$, and thus $d\mid a+b$
- I let you consider the other cases, i.e. $d\mid a+b$, $d\mid a$ and $d\mid a+2b$.

Comment: If d is not divisible for both b and (a+b) as well as both a and (a+2b), what will happen? I think we should consider those cases.

Comment: @FactorY This will not happen, since $d$ is prime.

Comment: @FactorY The idea is this: in the *field* $\,\Bbb F_p\,$ = integers $\!\bmod p\,$ (or in any integral domain) we have: $\, x(y+x) = 0 = y(y+2x) \iff x=0=y,\,$ i.e. the union of the $y$ axis and line $y=-x$ meets the union of the $x$ axis and line $y=-2x$ only at the origin $\,(x,y)=(0,0).\,$  The proof is easy:  $\,x(y+x)\,\Rightarrow x=0\,$ or $\,y = -x.\,$ If $\,x=0\,$ then $\,0 = y(y+2x) = y^2\Rightarrow\, y=0.\,$ If $\,y = -x\,$ then $\, 0 = y(y+2x) = -x(x)\,\Rightarrow\, x=0\,\Rightarrow\, y=-x =-0 = 0\ \ \ $